# Re render component after fetching searched data in Material UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm using Material UI Autocomplete to get searched data, it works fine, **but it's re-render after the search runs and clears the value without focus, then we have to click again to get fetched value.**

here Is my auto-complete component

```
<AutoCompleteNewDesign
    disableClearable
    freeSolo
    id="combo-box-demo"
    onChange={(e, selectValue) => {
        setInvoiceSelectedData(selectValue);
    }}
    options={invoiceSearchList}
    getOptionLabel={option => (option ? String(option?.data1) : '')}
    renderOption={option => (
        <div>
            {option.data1} - {option.data2}
         </div>
    )}
    renderInput={params => (
        <TextField 
            params={params}
            name="name-here"
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={e => {
                dispatch(
                    searchName(e.target.value);
                }}
            />
    )}
    filterOptions={filterOptions}
/>
```

I used this reducer to store data which fecth when user searched

```
  const { searchedNames } = useSelector(state => state.searchReducer);
```

How to call my dispatch asynchronous as well as prevent this re-render

Comment: You can either use `memo` or use controlled version of `TextField`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Show what you have tried.